# no matching function for call to... error with template class

Tags: c++, gcc

i have to do a generic double linked list, and i made it in vc++ 2010, and everything worked well,  but i have to compile it with gcc, but it can't compile it. When i call a method which has an iterator as parameter, i got this error:

```
no matching function for call to 'DLList<int>::Erase(DLList<int>::iterator, DLList<int>::iterator)'| 
[...]note: candidates are: void DLList<T>::Erase(DLList<T>::iterator&, DLList<T>::iterator&) [with T = int]|
```

The DLList is in a .h file, and every method defined inline. The iterator class is also in the DLList class.

```
template<typename T>
class DLList{
[...]
public: 
[...]
    void Erase(iterator &_first, iterator &_last){...}
    iterator first(){...}
    iterator last(){...}
[...]
    class iterator{...}
[...]
};
```

And the code which causes the error:

```
iList.Erase(iList.first(), iList.last());
```

(iList: DLList< int> iList)

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Erase(iterator const &_first, iterator const &_last){...}
```

This allows your temporary iterators, returned from `first()` and `last()`, to be passed. You cannot get a non-const reference to a temporary.

Alternatively, you could use this function signature and work on iterator copies (if you e.g. need to modify them within `Erase`):

```
void Erase(iterator _first, iterator _last){...}
```

Comment: This worked well. Instead of modify the erase function's signature, i declared 2 iterators after the list (it1 and it2), then iList.Erase(it1=iList.first(), it2=iList.last()); was good.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a non-const reference cannot be bound to a temporary. The result of `first()` and `last()` are temporaries, and those cannot be bound by the references in the signature of `Erase`.